# Create partition on CentOS server?

Tags: centos, partition

I have a headless CentOS server that I'd like to create a new partition on so I have a separate boot and data partition. I have an existing server with the setup that I want to achieve and running fdisk -l looks like this:

```
Disk /dev/cciss/c0d0: 299.9 GB, 299966445568 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 36468 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes

           Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/cciss/c0d0p1   *           1          13      104391   83  Linux
/dev/cciss/c0d0p2              14       36468   292824787+  8e  Linux LVM

Disk /dev/cciss/c0d1: 899.8 GB, 899898718208 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 109406 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes

           Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/cciss/c0d1p1   *           1      109406   878803663+  83  Linux
```

Here's the same command on my server:

```
Disk /dev/cciss/c0d0: 587.1 GB, 587128266752 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 71380 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes

           Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/cciss/c0d0p1   *           1          13      104391   83  Linux
/dev/cciss/c0d0p2              14       71380   573255427+  8e  Linux LVM
```

I've been told it's not as straightforward as creating a partition and setting mount-points to it because of the additional logical volume layer on CentOS. How can I create a partition without causing problems to the  data structure?

Comment: That first server has 2 separate disks, not one disk in multiple partitions (or at least it's configured to appear as such in the raid controller). Secondly, that output shows you're using LVM. Why not create a logical volume? This is exactly what LVM is for.